# Why is water an Arrhenius acid?

Tags: acid-base, water

Is water an Arrhenius acid? We define Arrhenius acidity with respect to water, but what will water itself be? It can donate $\ce{H+}$ as well as $\ce{OH-}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphoterism

Comment: Is it or is it not?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/4064/34388

Comment: It would be a bronsted acid  acid though,right? @DHMO

Comment: As well as a bronsted base.

Comment: I gave a test right now, it said water isn't an Arrhenius acid,thus the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> We define Arrhenius acidity with respect to water

That definition is new to me, whatever it is. The definition I know is:

> An Arrhenius acid is a substance that dissociates in water to form $\ce{H+}$ ions.
>
> An Arrhenius base is a substance that dissociates in water to form $\ce{OH-}$ ions.

The key concept to answer the question is the self-ionisation of water given in equation $(1)$.

$$\ce{H2O <<=> H+ + OH-}\tag{1}$$

This ionisation happens in water, and the ion product as written in equation $(2)$ is $10^{-14}$.

$$K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}] [\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-14}\tag{2}$$

Thus, water qualifies as a substance that dissociates in water to form $\ce{H+}$ ions. It also qualifies as a substance that dissociates in water to form $\ce{OH-}$ ions. It is both an Arrhenius acid and an Arrhenius base and thus the only Arrhenius amphoteric compound.

Comment: Aren't there other molecules which can donate both $OH^-$ and $H^+$? (I can imagine some organic ones, though I have no examples at hand.) Those would also be Arrhenius amphoteric, right?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I’m pretty sure there aren’t. Frankly, I don’t know a single organic molecule that *dissociates* to give $\ce{OH-}$. (Side note: [Use `mhchem` for chemical expressions; it prevents italics and inserts better spacing](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3046).)

Comment: What about [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/4064/34388)?

Comment: @DHMO What about that?

Comment: Well, that claims neither acidic nor basic.

Comment: @DHMO It claims that *the pH value of water* will be neither acidic nor basic. The post itself clearly says that water is both an Arrhenius acid and an Arrhenius base.

Comment: "dissociates to give $\ce{OH-}$" pretty sure t-butyl alcohol does.

Comment: @DHMO Source, please. (Spoiler: I’m pretty sure you won’t find one.)

Comment: What is the first step of the SN1 reaction of t-butyl alcohol?

Comment: @DHMO Please start by showing whether *tert*-butanol takes part in $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions. Note: Having $\ce{HI}$ or similar as the nucleophile does not count because the hydrogen-*tert*-butanol cation has different properties (and also dissociates to give water and not hydroxide).